# Rock Paper Scissors with Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a Python project that is a rock paper scissors game with a Tkinter GUI (Just began to code in Python). I have made buttons to click and want them to add an int to `playerChoice`. `playerChoice` is a variable that is either a 1,2 or 3. 1 is rock, 2 is paper and 3 is scissors. I cannot figure out how to do this. I have already made a function that adds 1 to playerChoice when I click the rock button but still it still will not work. The code looked a bit like this:

```
playerChoice = 0
def rockSelected(pC):
    pC += 1

rockButton = Button(window, text="Rock", command=rockSelected(playerChoice))
```

But it just did not print when I tried to print "rock" if playerChoice = 1
I do not know what I should do right now here is what I have

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Rock Paper Scissors")
window.geometry('600x400')

winLabel = Label(window, text="You won")
loseLabel = Label(window, text="You lose")
drawLabel = Label(window, text="It is a draw")

rockButton = Button(window, text="Rock")#, command= has to give me an int value of 1
rockButton.pack()

"""Make an if statement to check
if it is rock paper or scissors
like this
if value == 1:
playerchoice = 1
playerchoice is rock paper or scissors""" 

rockButton.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=30, width=60, x=100, y=100)
paperButton = Button(window, text="Paper")
paperButton.pack()
paperButton.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=30, width=60, x=230, y=100)

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

window.mainloop()
```

---

> **Copy comment**: now my code looks like this
>
> ```
> # Instantiate a Button widget with parent=window
> rockButton = Button(window, text="Rock") 
>
> # bind the function `playerChoice` 
> # to the "<Button-1>" event (left mouse button)
> rockButton.bind("<Button-1>", playerChoice) 
>
> # Layout the Button widget in the parent widget == window
> rockButton.pack() 
>
> # Define a function to used as event callback
> # Needs to have a `event` parameter
> def playerChoice(event): 
>     # Get the bound widget from the `event` object
>     w = event.widget  # <= the Button widget
>
>     # The widget is of type `Button`
>     # Get the Button `text=`
>     choice = w['text']
>
>     # Print the event.widget['text'] value
>     print('Player choice:{}'.format(choice))
>
>     # Do according to the `choice` the actions
>     if choice == 'Rock': 
>         # Do the Rock action
>         pass
>     elif choice == 'Paper': 
>         # Do the Paper action
>         pass
> ```

Comment: Read [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Comment: Instead of ***"command= has to give me an int value of 1"***, use [get the `Button['text' on click]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55735566/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl could You please send me the code because I don't understand what you wrote. Sorry for being so stupid but I just began coding

Comment: ok thanks. I hope i will understand what this code means, however, it works for me

Comment: @Weevez ***" i will understand what this code means"***: See my update comments